# Why doesn't setting the width of a horizontal list item working?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set the width on one of the list items to 50%. The horizontal list should be 100% width. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y9mwk2ut/1/)

## HTML

```
<ul>
     <li id="item1">hello</li>
     <li id="item2">world</li>
</ul>
```

## CSS

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 100%;
  padding: none;
}

ul li {
  display: inline;
}

#item1 {
  width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: check your condition again width 'display:inline' rule. Because when you use width 50% and display: inline and when there is enough space second element coming after first. Instead of display: inline use display: inline-block;

Comment: try with inline-block;

Comment: you are trying to do something, that's good. But where is your question? Where is your problem? Where are more details?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its display `inline-block`

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 100%;
  padding: none;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

#item1 {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li id="item1">hello</li>
<li id="item2">world</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Give `display: inline-block;` instead of `display: inline;`

```
ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y9mwk2ut/2/)**

Check different display property [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/)

Comment: @VickyGonsalves It's depend on OP. What they like.

Answer (score 2):

`li` display should be `inline-block`

```
ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: @ketan answered 30 secs earlier xD

Comment: Haha he was too fast!

Comment: Yeap haha)) may be next time you will win this competition ;)